# Obtain a ReadStream of the Redis database

Tags: node.js, redis, leveldb

In `LevelUP` it is very simple to iterate all keys and values using [readable stream](http://git.io/0XKz1Q).

How can I do get all records (**both** *keys* and *values*) from Redis store (may be as `ReadStream`)?

May be should I use [SCAN](http://redis.io/commands/scan) command?

Answer (score 1):

There is the [`redis-scanstreams`](https://github.com/brycebaril/redis-scanstreams) module that does exactly that.